# How do you input Cantonese characters in Android?

Tags: input-methods, text-input

I am able to use handwriting to input Chinese characters.
However, I would like to input Cantonese characters
(which are slightly different from Chinese characters).
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Cantonese Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.cantonese)**. Install the keyboard and add it as an input method. You can then use any of the following to input characters:

> - Pinyin (Yale, Jyutping and Cantonese Pinyin standards)
> - Cangjie
> - Handwriting
> - Voice
> - Stroke

Answer (score 0):

You can first try the solution provided by Huey. Alternatively you can also try these,

1. Install [Google Handwriting Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.handwriting.ime) and enable it.
2. Select the `Cantonese` language under the `Configure languages` option.
3. Now select `Download languages` (Download size around 12MB)
4. Now choose `Select Google Handwriting Input` and select the `Cantonese` keyboard.

Now you will be able to use the Cantonese Handwriting input and write in Cantonese.